# Access denied acccessing this file or folder. Cloud9

Tags: python, django, cloud9-ide

When i am creating a file in django and trying to save it too the file `App1`it gives me an error… `Access denied acccessing this file or folder`

[image]

This link shows how my files look.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ownership of the Django files and make sure that the user you are running the application as has permissions to the files. If you created it under a different user than you are running it under you will not have permissions to modify.

Comment: How do i check the ownership of the files? Also i created the files using the bash.

Comment: `ls -al`on the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

try running this command

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user App1/
```

or

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user  mywebsite/
```